# How did they get rid of the money in the bank?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

In the film Now You See Me the Four Horsemen rob the bank Crédit Républicain de Paris.  Thaddeus Bradley gives an explanation which includes:

> the money being switched with a flash paper copy which was burned after being put in the vault.

Was it explained how this got this to happen after the money was in the vault and there was no one there to burn it?

Comment: *sigh* yep - def duplicate, I should have searched first - rookie mistake!!

Comment: @Stefan yep, you should have ;)